# Returning a Row for a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a button that brings back certain values from two arrays. The Goal is to analyze two sheets and bring back the differences between the two. Unfortunately I can only get excel to bring back the PK.

I have tried multiple vLookups that say they will bring back a row but they do not work. It may have to do with the values being on different sheets in the workbook.

```
'These formulas return the primary Keys but I would still like the macro to 
'bring back The entire Row.  
Sub IndexMatch_Formula()
' Index Match Formula
    Dim Wa As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Analysis").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    With Wa
        'C
        .Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(IF(ISNA(IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"""",A2))=TRUE,A2,"""")=0,"""",IF(ISNA(IF(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0))=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,B:B,0)),"""",A2))=TRUE,A2,""""))"
        .Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Analysis").Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
    End With

End Sub

Sub IndexMatch_Formula_HP_ServiceManager()
' Index Match Formula
    Dim Wa As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Analysis").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Wa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    With Wa
        'D
        .Range("D2").Formula = "=IF(IF(ISNA(IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,0))=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),"""",B2))=TRUE,B2,"""")=0,"""",IF(ISNA(IF(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,0))=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),"""",B2))=TRUE,B2,""""))"
        .Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Analysis").Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
    End With

End Sub
```

I currently get the answer I'm looking for but the issue is I still have to go and get the rest of the data after my macro runs.

Comment: please edit your question and correct the code tags. Right now, part of the code shows as question text, which makes it difficult to identify the code.

Answer (score 1):

Any lookup formula like Vlookup or Index/Match will only ever return the value of a **single** cell.

If you need to return a complete row of data, you can use Match() to find the row number and then use that row number to retrieve the other cells in the row in subsequent formulas or code.

Comment: I ended up just using a Vlookup and replicating the code numerous times to retrieve all the necessary row columns. Thank you for your help.